# Remove shared items in a list in prolog

Tags: list, sorting, prolog

I have been trying to program a function that takes two lists, and returns a list of the items from list one that DO NOT APPEAR in the list 2. This is the code I have so far. The road block that I am running into is that I can't figure out how to test false on my member() line.

```
%remove_them/3
remove_them([H|T],List,[Newhead|NewTail]):-
    not(member(H,List)),
    Newhead is H,
    remove_them(T,List,NewTail).

remove_them([H|T],List,NewList):-
    member(H,List),
    remove_them(T,List,NewList).
```

Comment: Instead of `not/1` try using `/+` or even better use a conditional `-> ;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to say when this recursion should end (first line):

```
remove_them([],_,[]).
remove_them([H|T],List,[H|NewTail]):- 
    \+(member(H,List)), 
    remove_them(T,List,NewTail).
remove_them([H|T],List,NewList):- 
    member(H,List), 
    remove_them(T,List,NewList).

?- remove_them([1,2,e],[a,4,1],L).
L = [2, e] ;
false.

?- remove_them([r,2,3],[a,4,1,e],L).
L = [r, 2, 3] ;
false.
```

As pointed out from [Guy Coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1243762/guy-coder) there is also the possibility of [ordered sets](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ordsets). In SWI Prolog you can use this functionality to shorten/optimize your code. Please note that duplicates can not appear within sets:

```
remove_them2(Ori, Minus, Erg):-
    list_to_ord_set(Ori, Sori),
    list_to_ord_set(Minus, Sminus),
    ord_subtract(Sori, Sminus, Erg).

?- remove_them2([r,2,3],[a,4,1,e],L).
L = [2, 3, r].

?- remove_them2([1,2,e],[a,4,1],L).
L = [2, e].

?- remove_them2([a,a,a,b,b],[b,1,2],L).
L = [a].
```

Comment: Have you looked at using [ordered sets](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ordsets)? I don't plan to answer this but am thinking the code would look nicer if done using and ordered set predicate.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I did not know that these libraries exist. But it makes sense.